# How can I write Input Number float numbers as 2 decimals?

Tags: c#, html, razor

VFApprovedActual, and VFApprovedFinalEffort are float numbers. How can I write it as 2 decimal.
Thank you

```
   <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                        <Label For="() => Model.VFApprovedActual" />
                        <InputNumber class="form-control" @bind-Value="Model.VFApprovedActual" />
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                        <Label For="() => Model.VFApprovedFinalEffort" />
                        <InputNumber class="form-control" @bind-Value="Model.VFApprovedFinalEffort" />
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add step="0.01" to `InputNumber`:

```
 <InputNumber class="form-control" @bind-Value="Model.VFApprovedFinalEffort" step=0.01 />
```